# PL/SQL - stored substring procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, substring

I am doing a job interview PL/SQL question, and I am really stuck. Could someone help?

**Create stored procedure to return substrings from input string value. Substring delimiter shall be input parameter.**

**Task description**

Stored procedure shall have input parameters:

```
•   STRING
•   DELIMITER //any symbol
•   STRING_NUMBER //number of substring to be returned

Input example: STRING => ‘one,two,three’,
                            DELIMITER => ‘e’,
                            STRING_NUMBER => null
Output shall be: ‘on’
                              ‘,two,thr’
                              ‘’
                              ‘’

If STRING_NUMBER => 2, output shall be: ‘,two,thr’
```

EDIT:

First, I am trying to trim a string using TRIM function, but that doesn't work. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE substring
(STRNG IN VARCHAR2,DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2)
IS
instring VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
instring:= TRIM(DELIMITER FROM STRNG);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(instring);
END;

set serveroutput on
BEGIN
substring('marc','a');
END;
```

EDIT 2:

This does the part on the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE substring
(STRNG IN VARCHAR2,DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2)
IS
instring VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
instring:= REPLACE(STRNG,DELIMITER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(instring);
END;

set serveroutput on
BEGIN
substring('marc','a');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE substring
(STRNG IN VARCHAR2,DELIMITER IN VARCHAR2, STRING_NUMBER IN NUMBER)
IS
replace_string VARCHAR2(100);
instring NUMBER;
comma_counter NUMBER;
substring VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
replace_string:= REPLACE(STRNG,DELIMITER);
comma_counter:=REGEXP_COUNT(STRNG,',');
instring:=INSTR(STRNG,',',1,comma_counter-STRING_NUMBER+1);
substring:=SUBSTR(replace_string,instring);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(replace_string);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(','||substring);

END;

set serveroutput on
BEGIN
substring('one,two,three,four','e',2);
END;
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `substring('one,two,three,four',',',2);`

Comment: @Gary_W, It is debatable because the comma character is kinda special in this case. You should not call the procedure on comma character. Rather, only use letters. As I say, it is debatable. If someone has a better solution, please provide it.